# Why won't my CD run when I load it in the drive in my Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, installation, compact-disc, optical-drive

Why won't my Quicken installation disk run when I load it in the CD drive of my Windows 8.1 computer?  When the disc was put in the computer's tray, the tray closed and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you checked your AutoPlay settings?

Comment: Windows 8.2? But for the AutoPlay: http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Autoplay-Settings-in-Windows-8

Comment: Fixed to be 8.1 since 8.2 isn't beta yet. Even then, 8.2 would be beta software, which is out of scope on SU.

Comment: If you check the drives under 'This Computer' do you see the CD-ROM drive listed there with a drive letter?

Answer (score 1):

As of Windows 7 automatically playing the software content on a CD, DVD or BluRay is DISABLED by default in Windows.
It is just too much of an easy way for a virus to get automatically started.

You can right-click on the CD icon in Explorer and launch the application that would have auto-played (the setup in your case) from there if you want.

To make that the default behavior see the link posted by Rik in the comments.

Comment: `As of Windows 7 automatically playing the software content on a CD, DVD or BluRay is DISABLED by default in Windows. It is just too much of an easy way for a virus to get automatically started.` In this case, it really *is* “a feature, not a bug”. ツ